# How to treat POST data incoming to Magento

Tags: magento2, post-data

I prepare little integration for Magento 2.1 with some other app, comunicating with reqeusts containing `$_POST` data. Are there any good practices how to treat such a data incoming to store? Should I `trim()` it and `strip_tags()` and so on? Or there are some steps performed by Magento or PHP by themselves?

Comment: Use `Zend_Validate`, `$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['desc']), 'NotEmpty')) {}`